# htaccess Redirects Not Working Right

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My web page URLs should start with https://www. Some of my redirects are not working right. The example I will put is:

```
romancestuck.com/aboutus/amycunningham.htm
```

should redirect to:

```
https://www.romancestuck.com/aboutus.htm
```

but instead it gets stuck in a redirect loop.

The code in my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### REDIRECT NON-WWW TO WWW - START ###
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
### REDIRECT NON-WWW TO WWW - END ###

### REDIRECT NON-HTTPS TO HTTPS - START ###
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
### REDIRECT NON-HTTPS TO HTTPS - END ###

redirect 301 /aboutus/amycunningham.htm https://www.romancestuck.com/aboutus.htm
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^aboutus/amycunningham\.htm$ https://www.romancestuck.com/aboutus.htm [L,NC,R=302]

### REDIRECT NON-WWW TO WWW & REDIRECT NON-HTTPS TO HTTPS ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.romancestuck.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Remember to test this in a new browser or clear browser cache before testing.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.