# htaccess Custom Redirects not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been searching all over the place, but can't seem to get it working.

This code is running perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/?artists/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir1/artist.php?artist_id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?tour/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir2/index.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?video/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir3/index.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?news/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir4/article.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

However, after this I try this below, and there is no response at all from the server. It just loads the old page (still on the server)

## my custom redirect attempts, tried and not working

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old_dir//old_file.html /artists/subdir/21/biography/
RewriteRule /old_dir//old_file.html /artists/subdir/21/biography/ [L,R=301]
```

Anyone knows how to set the custom redirects after the first RewriteRules?

ps. not even @anubhava's answer works ([htaccess Redirects Not Working Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474525/htaccess-redirects-not-working-right))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is the problem for `301` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old_dir/old_file\.html$ /artists/subdir/21/biography/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?artists/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir1/artist.php?artist_id=$1&page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?tour/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir2/index.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?video/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir3/index.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?news/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ /dir4/article.php?artist_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

btw I see no relation of this problem with the linked answer (that answer is for adding `www` and `https`)

Hope my answer works this time for you :)

Comment: But you still are the genius! Thanks so much for solving this! And sorry about not reading the other question right. Quite the illiterate here on this.